# Efficient way to check for existing related documents in NoSQL (Firestore)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Following Current Datamodell

```
User
  User ID

Video
   VideoID
   LikedBy (Subcol) 
       User ID
       User ID
       User ID
```

Now if a User visits a video I wanna show if he Liked the Video already or not (similar to youtubes button color if you liked already).

My current approach is querieing for a Document with the Key of the signed In UserID and if I find one it means the user liked the video. The problem is I have this for Artists that you can subscribe too similar to channels on youtube.

This alone created about 3x the initial Reads I have on Page Load.
I would like to hear if there is any more efficient way to query for such a thing or structure the data.

Be aware that if you suggest me to store all liked Shows in the User or Show Document that this is not scalable due to the 1MB Limit.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can have a subcollection on the Users, storing the ids of the posts the likes.

2) You can create a `users_likes`, collections where the Ids is the user id and inside have an array with the ids of the posts the user likes.

3) Last, just make props called likes on the user collection an store the ids of the posts.

All options have a trade-off, I would make like a user and posts_likes query on load and keep that in memory (no external user is going to affect this).

`Be aware that if you suggest me to store all liked Shows in the User or Show Document that this is not scalable due to the 1MB Limit.`

If you are expecting a user to like more than 1 millions of posts... otherwise, storing 1Mb of only ids is a good idea... I use this same pattern for a `user events` tracking, I have events defined (equivalent to your posts) and the user make actions that correlate to those events (your likes), I have cases with more than 80K and it works like charm. I gave your 3 options, I would say, start with 3 until it doesnt work, then go to 2 and same process up to 1. Since you will work with array of ids, support yourself with [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)

Comment: Yes the 1 Solution is basicly my current one with the difference that I store the likes on a Subcollection of the Show instead of the User, second solution basicly has me making an additional read too, the problem with the third is that If I want a total like Counter on the show I could set up a trigger on the subcollection when a like gets added, I cant do such thing with the User document because other changes to it could happen frequently and would trigger the function an unneeded amount of time.

Comment: the benefit of keeping it to on user if that you can call it once and use it many times and save those reads

Comment: so basically you want to make a 0 extra read? I would stress that much focusing on read/writes... I dont know how advanced you are on your project that the blaze plan give like a lot of bandwidth to play and stay on the free tier

Comment: Its not about one extra read, but having 2 extra reads (following and liked) per Video clicked gets a lot often, so I wanted to ask a way around it, ur 3. approach sounds good but leaves me worried about a implementation to count the likes of a video (increment via gloud function)

Comment: you have 2 millions of free invocations per day, start with that, change it if you need it, ive implemented that pattern several times and my wallet is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

> My current approach is querieing for a Document with the Key of the signed In UserID and if I find one it means the user liked the video.

Yes, that's a correct approach.

> This alone created about 3x the initial Reads I have on Page Load.

I don't know where this is coming from but there is certainly something wrong. Unfortunately, nothing in your question can help me see the problem.

> I would like to hear if there is any more efficient way to query for such a thing or structure the data.

I don't understand much from your schema, but I would structure the database this way:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |    |
   |    --- uid (document)
   |         |
   |         --- //user properties
   |
   --- video (collection)
        |
        --- videoId (document)
             |
             --- likedBy: ["uid", "uid", "uid"]
```

As you can see, `likedBy` property is of type array. So once you get a video document, you can simply check the `uid` of the logged in user against the `likedBy` array. If it exists, it means that user has already liked that video, otherwise has not.

Comment: Thats a good approach the problem is how would you count the total likes of a video? By counting the Array length in the frontend?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, get the size of the `likedBy` array.